# (laravel 5.7) what is the problem in this request !! validation done but data insertion is not happening as expected

Tags: laravel, validation

First I'm sorry for my english.
I have a form with somme input and checkbox with dynamic id ,for example checkbox[] , input name="pointage_j[] ...

validation in the controller is done but insertion data in table not as expected, for example when pointage_j.1 = 1 and pointage_j.2 = 1 all insertion is done perfectly but when pointage_a.1 or pointage_2.1 all data insertion done with first id_employee . I can't understand where is my error !!

form :

```
@php
    $nbr = count($employees);
@endphp

{{Form::hidden("nbr", $nbr)}}

<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('date_pointage', 'Date du pointage')}}
    {{Form::date('date_pointage', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Date du pointage'])}}
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-md-1 align-middle" scope="col">N°</th>
        <th class="col-md-2 align-middle">Nom Prénom</th>
        <th class="col-md-1 align-middle" scope="col">Présence_J</th>
        <th class="col-md-1 align-middle" scope="col">Présence_N</th>
        <th class="col-md-1 align-middle" scope="col">Absence</th>
        <th class="col-md-2 align-middle" scope="col">Heurs Sup</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @php $i = 0; @endphp
    @foreach($employees as $employee)
        @php $i = $i + 1; @endphp
        <tr>
            <th> @php echo $i ; @endphp</th>
            <td>{{$employee ->nom_employee}} {{$employee ->prenom_employee}}</td>
            <td>{{Form::checkbox("pointage_j[]", 1, 0,['id' => "pointage_j.$i"]) }}</td>
            <td>{{Form::checkbox("pointage_n[]", 1, 0,['id' => "pointage_n.$i"]) }}</td>
            <td>{{Form::checkbox("pointage_absence[]", 1, 0,['id' => "pointage_absence.$i"]) }}</td>
            <td>{{Form::text("heur_sup[]", '0', ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>"heur_sup.$i"])}}</td>

            {{Form::hidden("employee_id[]", $employee->id,['employee_id'=>"employee_id.$i"])}}
        </tr>

    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Enregistrer</button>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Store method in my controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'nbr'                => 'required|integer',
        'employee_id.*'      => 'required|integer',
        'date_pointage'      => 'required|date',
        'pointage_j.*'       => 'accepted',
        'pointage_n.*'       => 'accepted',
        'pointage_absence.*' => 'accepted',
        'heur_sup.*'         => 'nullable|integer|between:0,5',
    ]);

    $nbr = $request->input('nbr');

    for ($i = 0; $i < $nbr; $i++) {
        if ($request->has("pointage_j.$i")) {
            $pointage_j = 1;
        } else {
            $pointage_j = 0;
        }

        if ($request->has("pointage_n.$i")) {
            $pointage_n = 1;
        } else {
            $pointage_n = 0;
        }

        if ($request->has("pointage_absence.$i")) {
            $absence = 1;
        } else {
            $absence = 0;
        }
        $pointage = new Pointage;
        $pointage->employee_id = $request->input("employee_id.$i");
        $pointage->date_pointage = $request->input("date_pointage");
        $pointage->jour_pointage = $pointage_j; //$request->has("pointage_j.$i") ? 1 : 0
        $pointage->nuit_pointage = $pointage_n;
        $pointage->absence_pointage = $absence;
        $pointage->heurs_sup_pointage = $request->input("heur_sup.$i");
        $pointage->save();
    }

    return redirect('/pointages')->with('success', 'Enregistrement reussi');
}
```

after a day of breaking my head, I found the solution.
I used an input field hidden before the chekbox and I used vanila javascript to change the value of the input hidden 0 by default and if the checkbox is checked the value changes to 1. in my controller I ignore the checkbox and I takes only the value of the hidden input.
just a note the hidden input must be before the checkbox without space or line break. I put the code of the view and the controller maybe it will be useful for someone.

my view create :

```
  {!! Form::open(['action' =>'PointagesController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
@csrf

@php
    $nbr = count($employees);
@endphp
{{Form::hidden("nbr", $nbr)}}

<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('date_pointage', 'Date du pointage')}}
    {{Form::date('date_pointage', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Date du pointage'])}}
</div>
<table  class="table table-bordered" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-1 align-middle" scope="col">N°</th>
            <th class="col-md-2 align-middle">Nom Prénom</th>
            <th class="col-md-1 align-middle" scope="col">Présence_J</th>
            <th class="col-md-1 align-middle" scope="col">Présence_N</th>
            <th class="col-md-1 align-middle" scope="col">Absence</th>
            <th class="col-md-2 align-middle" scope="col">Heurs Sup</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @php $i = 0; @endphp

    @foreach($employees as $employee)

        <tr>
            <th colspan="1" width=30> {{$loop->iteration}}</th>
            <td>{{$employee ->nom_employee}} {{$employee ->prenom_employee}}</td>


            <td>{{Form::hidden("pointage_j_$i",0,['id' => "pointage_j_$i"])}}{{ Form::checkbox("pointage_j[]", 1, false,['onclick' => 'this.previousSibling.value=1-this.previousSibling.value'],['id' => "pointage_jj.$i"]) }}</td>

            <td>{{Form::hidden("pointage_n_$i",0,['id' => "pointage_n_$i"])}}{{ Form::checkbox("pointage_n[]", 1, false,['onclick' => 'this.previousSibling.value=1-this.previousSibling.value'],['id' => "pointage_nn.$i"]) }}</td>

            <td>{{Form::hidden("pointage_absence_$i",0,['id' => "pointage_absence_$i"])}}{{ Form::checkbox("pointage_absence[]", 1, false,['onclick' => 'this.previousSibling.value=1-this.previousSibling.value'],['id' => "pointage_absencee.$i"]) }}</td>

            <td>{{Form::text("heur_sup[]", '0', ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>"heur_sup.$i"])}}</td>


            {{Form::hidden("employee_id[]", $employee->id,['employee_id'=>"employee_id.$i"])}}
        </tr>
        @php $i = $i + 1; @endphp
@endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" >Enregistrer</button>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

my controller :

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'nbr'=>'required|integer',
        'employee_id.*'=>'required|integer',
        'date_pointage'=>'required|date',
        'pointage_j.*'=>'required|integer|between:0,1',
        'pointage_n.*'=>'required|integer|between:0,1',
        'pointage_absence.*'=>'required|integer|between:0,1',
        'heur_sup.*'=>'nullable|integer|between:0,5',
    ]);

   // dd($request->all());

    $nbr=$request->input('nbr');

    $i=0;
    while ($i < $nbr){

        $pointage = new Pointage;
        $pointage-> employee_id = $request->input("employee_id.$i");
        $pointage-> date_pointage = $request->input("date_pointage");
        $pointage-> jour_pointage = $request->input("pointage_j_$i");
        $pointage-> nuit_pointage = $request->input("pointage_n_$i");
        $pointage-> absence_pointage = $request->input("pointage_absence_$i");
        $pointage-> heurs_sup_pointage = $request->input("heur_sup.$i");
        $pointage-> save();
        $i++;
    }

    return redirect('/pointages')->with('success','Enregistrement reussi');

}
```

Comment: While insertion where exactly you're getting problem ? did you `dd($request->all())` in your controller

Comment: yes I did when for first id_employee $pointage_j = 1 and $absence = 1 for the next employee there all data is insert in ferst employees

Comment: array:7 [▼
  "_token" => "dNqBFFzUOtYAjO4DUTan76RPohaQvuGExUJpeRXR"
  "nbr" => "2"
  "date_pointage" => "2019-01-08"
  "pointage_j" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "1"
  ]
  "heur_sup" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "0"
    1 => "0"
  ]
  "employee_id" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "2"
    1 => "3"
  ]
  "pointage_absence" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "1"
  ]
]

Comment: You should try `dd($pointage)` just prior to `$pointage->save()` to see what data is going to be saved.  Ensure that the primary key for the table does not already exist.  If the primary key already exists, then save will not be able to insert a new record.

Comment: I just did it, actually the result of the request before the recording takes the first id_employee !!! but I really not understand why ,, where is the problem